# How to sum a subset of an multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, sas

I can't make a sum of all values in a subset of an multidimensional array??

**_sum = sum(of _valores[_i,_x,_quadrado,*]);**

I know that I can sum one dimension array
*E.G.* _sum = sum(of _arraName[*]);

Code::

```
data teste;
    array _quadros{3,3,9} _temporary_;
    array _valores{3,3,9,9} _temporary_;

    /*Zera todos os valores*/
    do _i = 1 to 9;
        do _z = 1 to 3;
            do _t = 1 to 3;
                do _x = 1 to 9;
                    _valores[_z,_t,_i,_x] = 1;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    do _quadrado = 1 to 9;
        do _i = 1 to 3;
            do _x = 1 to 3;
                _sum = sum(of _valores[_i,_x,_quadrado,*]);
                put _sum =;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Error::

> _sum = sum(of _valores[_i,_x,_quadrado,*]);
>
> ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.
>
> ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
>
> ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: Do you have PROC IML? If you want to do matrix math, its best to use the tool suited to such analysis.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question and could be useful for those with access to IML.

Comment: I dont have access =/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the sum function.  You can write your own to do it.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.fns;
function sumslice4(inArr[*,*,*,*],a,b,c,d) ;
    _1 = dim(inArr,1);
    _2 = dim(inArr,2);
    _3 = dim(inArr,3);
    _4 = dim(inArr,4);

    _s = 0;

    do i=1 to _1;
        do j=1 to _2;
            do k=1 to _3;
                do l=1 to _4;
                    if (a = i or missing(a)) and
                       (b = j or missing(b)) and
                       (c = k or missing(c)) and
                       (d = l or missing(d)) then

                        _s = sum(_s,inArr[i,j,k,l]) ;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    return (_s);
endsub;
run;
quit;
```

This creates a function `sumslice4()` that takes a 4 dimensional array, and a series of indices.  You specify the indices you want summed.  Optionally, put a missing, `.`, to specify the full index.

Here is a test with your example:

```
options cmplib=work.fns;

data test;
    array _values{3,3,9,9} _temporary_;
    do _i = 1 to 9;
        do _z = 1 to 3;
            do _t = 1 to 3;
                do _x = 1 to 9;
                    _values[_z,_t,_i,_x] = 1;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;

x = sumslice4(_values,1,1,.,.);
put x=;

x = sumslice4(_values,1,1,1,.);
put x=;

x = sumslice4(_values,1,1,1,1);
put x=;

x = sumslice4(_values,.,1,1,1);
put x=;
run;
```

I get:

```
x=81
x=9
x=1
x=3
```

Which should be what you are expecting.

Comment: I really can't believe that SAS don't have this option for sum. I just need to sum the last dimension. In my opinion is the same of an array with one dimension.

Comment: You have to understand how these are handled.  The Data Step really only has 1 dimensional arrays.  The ability to add multiple dimension is just syntactical sugar for easy indexing.  There is no real concept of dimension outside of that.  It was designed for processing large amounts of flat table structures very efficiently, not multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your data instead and use `PROC SUMMARY`.

```
* generate test data ;
data test;
  do i = 1 to 9;
    do z = 1 to 3;
      do t = 1 to 3;
        do x = 1 to 9;
          valores = 1;
          output;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

* Sum across last dimension ;
proc summary data=test nway ;
  class i z t ;
  var valores ;
  output out=want sum= ;
run;
```